# LAG function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Here is my query:

```
create table #t(id int,amt int)

insert into #t values(1, 100), (1, 200), (2, 300), (2, 500), (2, 800)

select 
    id, amt, 
    lag(amt, 1, null) over (partition by id order by amt) as prev_amt,
    lead(amt, 1, null) over (partition by id order by amt) as next_value
from #t
```

Returning:

```
id  amt   prev_amt  next_value
----------------------------
1   100   NULL      200
1   200   100       NULL
2   300   NULL      500
2   500   300       800
2   800   500       NULL
```

When I change the query to

```
select 
    id, amt,
    lag(amt, 1, null) over (partition by id order by amt desc) as prev_amt,
    lead(amt, 1, null) over (partition by id order by amt desc) as next_value
from #t
```

Result is:

```
id  amt prev_amt    next_value
1   200 NULL    100                    
1   100 200 NULL                        
2   800 NULL    500
2   500 800 300
2   300 500 NULL
```

I am not understanding why it gives this?

```
   id   amt prev_amt    next_value
    1   200 NULL    100
```

Previous amount is supposed to be 100?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can see that the two queries are different. Did you expect the change to have no effect? Why? Did you expect the change to have a different effect? What were you expecting?

Comment: first partition by and order by is executed then in that result,lag/lead work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` word here is `WINDOW` functions.
Actually you have working windows and these functions are working in those windows.

For first statement you have window:

```
/---------\
| 1   100 |
| 1   200 |
\---------/
```

For row 1 the previous value is NULL because you are out of window(above), next is 200. For row 2 previous is 100, next is NULL because you are out of window(below).

In second statement window has changed:

```
/---------\
| 1   200 |
| 1   100 |
\---------/
```

For row 1 the previous value is still NULL because you are out of window(above), next is 100. For row 2 previous is 200, next is still NULL because you are out of window(below).